# JIRA - Resource Availability and Utilization Tracking - Across multiple projects

Tags: resources, reporting, jira, conflict

Was wondering if anyone knows of a plugin for JIRA that would provide a consistent view on a daily / weekly / Monthly / etc. basis for People / Resource Tracking and forecasting of resource availability - especially if resource could be used on multiple "projects" potentially.

- Current Tasks assigned with duration and period of effort
- Future Tasks assigned with duration and period of effort
- Availability for assignment of tasks based on current and future items assigned already
- Conflict, overallocation, prioritization - ability to quickly see over / under subscription
- Ability for individuals to update progress on tasks
- Ability for managers to generate reports
- etc.

This is for a scenario if you have ~100+ people spread across 5 locations globally with different people managers and multiple Book of Works / multiple Projects, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We developed and support our JIRA add-on for resource planning and issue scheduling — [ActivityTimeline](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.activitytimeline.plugin).

ActivityTimeline provides weekly grid-based dashboard where rows are people, columns — days of week. Drag'n'drop a JIRA task to schedule it to some day; Resize or Move issues to change planned start/end dates. Everything is visible on one screen and you can move backward and forward across weeks.

Details at http://activitytimeline.com

Sorry if this sounds too commercial but hopefully it will be of use to some.

Answer (score 1):

Tempo- Timesheet
Feywa provides you with resource allocation and resource utilization feature but supports only JIRA 4.3.4.
In future, if you ever happen to upgrade your JIRA(which you obviously would), Feywa support will be lost.
i am looking forward to a solution for Resource allocation and resource utilization for JIRA 4.4.3. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need and have come across a recent announcement from Tempo http://www.tempoplugin.com/ of release of two new modules that I am hoping will address these needs, Tempo Planner and Tempo Books - http://blog.tempoplugin.com/2013/tm-software-introduces-a-project-and-portfolio-management-solution-for-atlassians-jira/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eazyBI reporting application with JIRA integration](https://eazybi.com/help/jira) to create ad-hoc JIRA issues reports based on any standard dimension (projects, components, reporters, assignees, issue types, priorities, statuses, time etc.) as well as using any custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still looking, this add-on might help : forecast.geertjan.it/ It allows you to assign future tasks to a period(s) and teams. It is multi-project and also shows team (over)allocation. Contact me, if you have questions.